# Can fruit be affected by antifreeze in soil?

Tags: botany

Due to an accident about 2L of car antifreeze (ethylene glycol & corrosion inhibitors) was spilled around the soil at the base of a fig tree. I am wondering if there is any way the antifreeze can enter the fruit? Will soil bacteria break it down over the course of time? I did a web search that indicated that antifreexe can be harmful to plant roots and can stunt their growth. I could not find any information indicating whether it has any chance of actually entering fruit. I wonder if the ethane glycol (ethane 1, 2 diol) molecule is too large to enter the root system. Your advice would be appreciated.

Kind regards
Chris